# Draw circular sector using Path

Tags: android, view, path, android-canvas

I would like to draw something like this:

[image]

So on each photo I would like to put a circular sector (cut arc) with black area. How can I achieve that with using e.g.

```
canvas.draw(Path path, Paint paint);
```

I tried below but it didn t work out as I would like to:

```
Path path = new Path();
path.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);
path.addCircle(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, getHeight() / 2, Path.Direction.CW);
path.addRect(0, getHeight() - 70, getWidth(), getHeight(), Path.Direction.CW);
```

Comment: What's your `minSdkVersion`?

Comment: take a look, maybe it helps http://www.curious-creature.com/2012/12/11/android-recipe-1-image-with-rounded-corners/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it working. You just need to clip the canvas before drawing and use `Path.FillType.INVERSE_EVEN_ODD` to draw your sector:

```
// Limit the drawable region of the canvas (saving the state before)
canvas.save();
canvas.clipRect(new Rect(0, canvas.getHeight() - 70, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight()));

Path path = new Path();
path.setFillType(Path.FillType.INVERSE_EVEN_ODD);
path.addCircle(canvas.getWidth() / 2, canvas.getHeight() / 2, canvas.getHeight() / 2, Path.Direction.CW);
path.addRect(0, canvas.getHeight() - 70, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), Path.Direction.CW);
canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

// Restore the canvas to the saved state to remove clip
canvas.restore();

// Draw more things on the canvas...
```

Alternativelly, you can use `Canvas.drawArc` ([documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawArc%28android.graphics.RectF,%20float,%20float,%20boolean,%20android.graphics.Paint%29))

I assume from you question that you need to assign a fix height for your sector, so you will need to compute `startAngle` and `sweepAngle` (parameters of the `drawArc` method) based on that height (assuming a square image). Here is the sample code (API level 15 compatible):

```
int sectorHeigh = 70; // The height of your sector in pixels

// Compute the start angle based on your desired sector height
float startAngle = (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.asin((canvas.getHeight() / 2f - sectorHeigh) / (canvas.getHeight() / 2f)));
// Add the arc (calculating the sweepAngle based on startAngle)
canvas.drawArc(new RectF(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight()), startAngle, 2 * (90 - startAngle), false, paint);
```

Another way to draw your sector using arcs is creating a `Path` object, add an arc using `Path.addArc` ([documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#addArc%28android.graphics.RectF,%20float,%20float%29)) and then use `Canvas.drawPath` ([documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawPath%28android.graphics.Path,%20android.graphics.Paint%29)) to draw it.

Comment: That's a great answer! Thanks :)